# Form only sends a max of nine dynamic rows

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, dynamic, smtp

I have a PHP file that is supposed to send a complex form to an email via the PEAR Mail package using an SMTP connection.
the form has a normal (HTML) form and a dynamic one (using JS). The dynamic one can be anywhere from 1 row to 150 rows. (The form is created for making furniture)

I can't seem to find the problem on why the form only sends a max of 9 dynamic rows. The array debug contains the right number of arrays for each test sending 5 or 50 rows of the dynamic form but the mail receives only a max of 9 rows and if I add more than 9 rows the form will not send anymore.

I will get the echo "Form data processed successfully!" every time, even if the form is sent to the specified address or not.[This is how the form looks in the final e-mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKHxp.png)

But will not send more the 9 rows for some reason...

This is part php:

```
$emailBody = "";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$formData = isset($data) ? $data : null;

//EXTRACT VALUES
$date = $formData['first-form-data-input'];
$adresa = $formData['first-form-adresa-firmei-input'];
$persoanaContact = $formData['first-form-persoana-contact-input'];
$telefon = $formData['first-form-telefon-input'];
$email = $formData['first-form-email-input'];
$adresaLivrare = $formData['first-form-adresa-livrare-input'];
$denumireComanda = $formData['first-form-denumire-comanda-input'];

// EXTRACT DYNAMIC FORM DATA
$table1 = [];
$table2 = [];

// Loop through dynamic data
foreach ($formData['dynamicFormData'] as $setKey => $set) {
   
    $table1[] = $set['nr_rand' . ($setKey + 1)];

    $table2Set = [];
    foreach ($set as $fieldKey => $fieldValue) {
        $table2Set[$fieldKey . ($setKey + 1)] = $fieldValue;
    }
    $table2[] = $table2Set;
}

// CREATE TABLE
$table1Html = '<table border="1"><tr><th>Column 1</th></tr>';
foreach ($table1 as $value) {
    $table1Html .= '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
}
$table1Html .= '</table>';

$table2Html = '<table border="1"><tr><th>Material</th><th>Lungime</th><th>Latime</th><th>Nr. Bucati</th><th>Fibra</th><th>Cant. Fata</th><th>Cant. Spate</th><th>Cant. Stanga</th><th>Cant. Dreapta</th><th>Cant. Grafica Div</th><th>Corp</th><th>Supliment</th></tr>';
foreach ($table2 as $row) {
    $table2Html .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $table2Html .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
    $table2Html .= '</tr>';
}
$table2Html .= '</table>';


// EMAIL BODY
$emailBody = "

<h2>Informatii client</h2>
    <table border=\"1\">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>$date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Denumire firma</td>
            <td>{$formData['first-form-denumire-firma-input']}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adresa firma</td>
            <td>$adresa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Persoana contact</td>
            <td>$persoanaContact</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Telefon</td>
            <td>$telefon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>$email</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adresa livrare</td>
            <td>$adresaLivrare</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Denumire comanda</td>
            <td>$denumireComanda</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    
    <h2> Informatii formular </h2>

    <table border=\"1\">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>Nr. rand</th>
            <th>Material</th>
            <th>Lungime</th>
            <th>Latime</th>
            <th>Nr. Bucati</th>
            <th>Fibra</th>
            <th>Cant Fati</th>
            <th>Cant Spate</th>
            <th>Cant Stanga</th>
            <th>Cant Dreapta</th>
            <th>Cant Grafica</th>
            <th>Corp</th>
            <th>Supliment</th>
        </tr>";

foreach ($table2 as $row) {
    $emailBody .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $emailBody .= '<td>' . ($value !== '' ? $value : '') . '</td>';
    }
    $emailBody .= '</tr>';
}

$emailBody .= '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with your code. PHP `max_input_vars` puts a limit on the number of variables a form can submit or it could be the `memory_limit` set in your `php.ini`. Email servers receiving the email might also have a limit on the size of email it will receive, and an email exceeding the limit could be truncated or sometimes not received at all.

Comment: You probably don't need to be sending an email containing all that data. You could save it to a database and let the recipient access it via your site, or you could write the contents to a file and send it as an attachment. I think gmail limits at 102kb but other services might be much lower, especially private emails.

Comment: _"The array debug contains the right number of arrays"_ - if you see the correct amount of data when you debug `$formData`(?), then this is not a problem of `max_input_vars`. We don't know the format of the data you are sending, so it is hard to say what exactly your code does. Can you please provide sample data in JSON form?

Comment: The form works fine if I have changed the testing email address. I was doing testing in Gmail but when I tested on a server email it did send all the data.